# how to write R function to find row names into column name and extract value?

Tags: r, indexing, match

I am a beginner in R.
I have two data frames and want to extract values where row names matches with coll names.
Can I use match function?

```
## dataframe 1 has 5 observations and its 5 element    
df = data.frame(x = c("P1","P2","P3","P4","P5"), 
                f_1 = c("NA","1","NA","NA","NA"), 
                f_2= c("NA","1","NA","NA","NA"),
                f_3= c("1","7","NA","NA","NA"),
                f_4= c("NA","NA","5","NA","NA"),
                f_5= c("NA","NA","2","NA","NA"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Dataframe 2 has 5 observations and their allias.
df2 = data.frame(x = c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5"),
                 f=c("f_1","f_20","f_30","f_4","f_15"))
```

## I want to match rows in headers

and my required output is :
create new column in new dataframe.

```
    x   f   New
    D1  P2  1
    D2  NA  NA
    D3  NA  NA
    D4  P3  5
    D5  NA  NA
```

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get it. Rownames of what should match column names of what?

Comment: Hi,i want to match each row of 2nd column in df2 with headers of df and if there is a match take that row value and row name in separate df3.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(f, New, -x) %>%         # reshape dataset
  filter(New != "NA") %>%        # remove "NA" rows
  right_join(df2, by = "f") %>%  # join to the other dataset
  select(x=x.y, f=x.x, New)      # select and rename columns of interest

#    x    f  New
# 1 D1   P2    1
# 2 D2 <NA> <NA>
# 3 D3 <NA> <NA>
# 4 D4   P3    5
# 5 D5 <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to reshape your `df` from wide to long format so that it's easier to filter-join the data to get the rows you require.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df = data.frame(x = c("P1","P2","P3","P4","P5"), 
                f_1 = c("NA","1","NA","NA","NA"), 
                f_2= c("NA","1","NA","NA","NA"),
                f_3= c("1","7","NA","NA","NA"),
                f_4= c("NA","NA","5","NA","NA"),
                f_5= c("NA","NA","2","NA","NA"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 = data.frame(x = c("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5"),
                 f=c("f_1","f_20","f_30","f_4","f_15"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# reshape df from wide to long format
longdf <- df %>% gather(f, fvalue, -x)

# to the data wrangling to get your required output
df3 <- df2 %>% 
    left_join(longdf, by = c("f" = "f")) %>% 
    rename(x = x.x, fx = f, f = x.y, New = fvalue) %>% 
    arrange(x, New) %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    slice(1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-fx)

df3
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   x     f     New  
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 D1    P2    1    
#> 2 D2    <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3 D3    <NA>  <NA> 
#> 4 D4    P3    5    
#> 5 D5    <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>